# create pivot table in pandas using count of occurrence of value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot, pivot-table

I'm attempting to create cross-table / pivot table in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two','two'],'bar': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C']})
```

however my attempts come up as:

```
pd.pivot(df, index='foo', columns='bar')
```

> TypeError: pivot_simple() got multiple values for argument 'index'

and the second:

```
pd.pivot_table(data = df, values = 'bar', index = 'bar', columns = 'foo', aggfunc=lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x))

foo one two
bar     
A   4.0 NaN
B   NaN 4.0
C   2.0 2.0
```

The output I'm looking to achieve is the below:

```
        A   B   C
one     2       1
two        2    1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Switch the `column` and `index` and use `len` as `aggfunc`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='foo', columns='bar', values='foo', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

#bar  A  B  C
#foo         
#one  2  0  1
#two  0  2  1
```

Or just use `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.foo, df.bar)

#bar  A  B  C
#foo         
#one  2  0  1
#two  0  2  1
```

Comment: nailed it, pd.crosstab works a charm!!!